# Can I work with XML, HTML and PHP at the same time in the same file?

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml

Basically what I am trying to do here is to get the selected value from the user and generate an input box if the selected value is member. My problem is that the HTML code written inside `echo` isnt understood by the computer. Can somebody explain and help me please?

My code where I have encountered the problem:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];
if (($food=="member")) {
    echo'Enter addditional details:<input type="text" name="optional">';
} else {
    echo "aint got ".$food;
}
echo'</response>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML elements inside of a XML as XML will think of them as of XML elements. I'd suggest returning only name of your input or if there is no name then 1 or 0 to determine if you should show your input and let php to generate the input.

> There are 5 pre-defined entity references in XML: *< > & " '*

If you need AJAX and call PHP for information processing then you shouldn't use XML as AJAX calls on XML are used to read data from files.

Look at differences of:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_xmlfile.asp

and

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that it's creating a non-valid XML document.

XML and HTML have a common style, BUT XML is a much more strict standard.  HTML can be very forgiving and the code would probably be displayed by most browsers, but XML has to have close tags for all elements.  The input tag isn't terminated properly and should be...

```
 echo'Enter addditional details:<input type="text" name="optional" />';
```

Note the / before the close >.  You could alternatively put

```
 echo'Enter addditional details:<input type="text" name="optional"></input>';
```